# Doubt about quantification of a generic piecewise function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, logic, taylor-expansion

There is a function $f\in \mathscr C^\infty(\mathbb R)$ such that

$f(x):=
\begin{cases}
 f(x)>0&\text{if}\, x> 0\\
 f(x)=0&\text{if}\, x\leq 0\\
\end{cases}$

in particular $f^{(k)}(0)=0\,\forall\,k\in\mathbb N$, so $f$ has in the origin Taylor's polynomials of every order, and those polynomials equal to zero. So $f(x)=o(x^n)$ as $x\to0$.

The question is:

Which of the following affirmation is true?

$\forall\, n\in\mathbb N \,\exists\, \delta>0:\forall \,x\in[0,\delta]\,f(x)\le x^n$

$\exists\,\delta>0\,:\forall \,n\in\mathbb N \,\forall \,x\in[0,\delta]\,f(x)\le x^n$

Now, I know that the second one is false, the explanation is because it implies that $f(x)=0\,\forall \,x\in[0,\delta]$.

Can someone explain me why it implies that? Is that related to the fact that $\delta$ is quantified before while in the first one in depends from $n$?

An example of such function is

$f(x):=
\begin{cases}
 e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}&\text{if}\, x> 0\\
 0&\text{if}\, x\leq 0\\
\end{cases}$

Comment: Are you sure there is not a typo in your first formula? The part before "if $x>0$" ought to be the value of $f(x)$, not a proposition.

Comment: And shouldn't you specify that the function is $\mathcal C^\infty$ rather than $\mathcal C^0$?

Comment: @HenningMakholm you're of course right, thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 1):

Note that for any sufficiently small $\gamma > 0$, $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \gamma^n = 0$. Then we have that $f(\gamma)$ is bounded above by $x^n \to 0$ for all $\gamma \in [0,\delta]$, which implies that $f(\gamma) \leq 0$. This is indeed due to the order of the quantifiers, since we choose a $\delta$ that satisfies the condition *for all* $n \in \mathbb{N}$. In the first case, the value of $\delta$ can vary depending upon $n$, so we do not encounter this issue.